# reading a file into an array iterated 4000 times is causing major bottleneck -- would like a quicker workaround

Tags: php, arrays, file-io, iteration

Goal:

- I have 4000 separate files
- 7 files are randomly chosen from the possible 4000 files available, and all of their file contents are combined into 1 file.
- The random choosing of 7 files and then combining into 1 file, is done 4000 times.
- When the 7 files are merged into 1, duplicate data is in the 1 file. I want to know which data is in the file exactly 6 times and print only that data out.
- Each of the 4000 file contains about 90000 lines of data, the data resembles serial numbers that look like "01 100 214 24 750000 37" on each line.

Bottleneck identified:
I have identified the bottleneck to be the reading in to an array of the 1 large file that has been created from the 7. This is done 4000 times -- By putting the file() statement outside the loop and having it all write to one file, the code runs in 2 minutes. With the file() statement in the loop writing to each new file, it would take 30 hours. I need the data to be put in separate files.

What has been tried: I have tried array_merge and array_intersect, they slow things down considerably. I have also tried reading in as a string and then exploding as well as str_split into an array, very slow results as well. THANK YOU*** for the read and any help.

Code:

```
  for($u=10; $u<=10; $u++)
   {
for($t=1; $t<=4000; $t++)
{

for($e=6; $e<=6; $e++)
    {


$file = fopen("automate_100_AllRounds5_twopairs_".$u."_".$t."_".$e.".txt", "w");
fclose($file);
            }

    }


 }
$hello_wn=range(0,39);

     $file = fopen("automate_speedier_track.txt", "w");
     $file2d = fopen("automate_speedier_track2.txt", "w");

    for($u=10; $u<=10; $u++)
    {
for($t=1; $t<4000; $t++)
{

shuffle($hello_wn);

for($e=6; $e<=6; $e++)
    {
    $picked[$a]=$u."_".$t."_".$e;
    $file2s = fopen("automate_100_AllRounds5_twopairs_".$picked[$a].".txt", "a");
    fwrite($file,$u."_".$t."_".$e."\r\n");
    fwrite($file2d,$hello_wn[0]." ".$hello_wn[1]." ".$hello_wn[2]." ".$hello_wn[3]." ".$hello_wn[4]." ".$hello_wn[5]." ".$hello_wn[6]."\r\n");

    $filez1=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[0].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez1."\r\n");
    $filez2=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[1].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez2."\r\n");
    $filez3=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[2].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez3."\r\n");
    $filez4=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[3].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez4."\r\n");
    $filez5=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[4].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez5."\r\n");
    $filez6=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[5].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez6."\r\n");
    $filez7=file_get_contents("automate_100_run_7_".$hello_wn[6].".txt");
    fwrite($file2s,$filez7."\r\n");

    ----THIS FILE() STATEMENT DIRECTLY BELOW CAUSES THE BOTTLENECK-----
    $lines1=file("automate_100_AllRounds5_twopairs_".$picked[$a].".txt");

    $lines1=array_map("trim",$lines1);
    $lines1=array_count_values($lines1);    

foreach($lines1 as $key => $val)
{
    if($lines1[$key] ==6)
    {
        fwrite($file2s,$key."\r\n");
    }
}

    fclose($file2s);
    $a++;
    }

    }


   }
   fclose($file);
   fclose($file2d);
```

Comment: why? /facepalm What are you trying to accomplish? Reading 90,000 lines of data into an array all at once is putting that into memory, of course its a bottleneck. Wisdom would say break it up into manageable pieces.

Comment: XY problem, there has to be a better way

Comment: @rottingham--I appreciate the response, in my intro I state what my end goal is, which is to write to file all data that is present 6 times in the file. Please read my notes, they are short and answer your question well, I think. Thank you.

Comment: @jszobody--Thank you! but I have tried databases and I had a ton of problems with mysql being able to handle all of those numbers. A night mare really. So painfully slow.

Comment: @Dagon--much appreciate your comment but what do you mean by XY problem? Any details you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not the reading of the 90000 lines of data that is the problem. It is the iteration of having to read in a new file 4000 times. I need help with a solution on how to get the data into an array only once but get it out to separate files from there.

Comment: @user3152377 A database will handle this many, many times faster than files, if you setup it up properly (indexes, etc). Plus you can get rid of duplicates right off the bat in your db queries.

Comment: @jszobody Thanks for the reply! I do not want to get rid of the duplicates, I want to print the duplicates that appear 6 times in the file out to a new file. I have tried mysql, with indexes, it was a nightmare. Sooooo Slow. I could not believe it until I did some heavy research and everyone admitted mysql really is not optimized for millions of numbers. Shocked me because my first instinct was to do a database. I reluctantly let go of the idea.

Comment: @user3152377 Millions of records will always present a performance challenge. However for all the slowness a DB will have with million of records, working with files will still be slower yet (hugely). That's why no one has actually posted answer here yet, every knows that it's ludicrous to do this.

Comment: @jszobody Thanks for the reply. As I said before I have tried doing this in a database, the database was clocking in at hours!!! I have to get it done in 5 mins. So I wrote this which is faster but it limits me to one file. Sorry to give you the bad news but this is faster than mysql trust me, I did not want to give up the mysql solution. I was forced to. Have you been programming long??? If so I think you would know that mysql is not the answer to everything.

Comment: @user3152377 You're very cute. I didn't say it had to be MySQL, you keep bringing that up. A database is the only reasonable option for massive amounts of data like this. I know because I do this. For a living. (Side note: how do you think sites like Facebook handle millions and billions of records? Text files?!?)

Comment: Is there anybody who can think outside the box and willing to try to help me? This is the first time I have ever had to post a question.

Comment: @jszobody if you do this for a living and you are on the forum to help people why don't you simply say to me there is something better than mysql and tell me what that database is. Remember I am not a company, so mysql is what I have easy access to. I have been nothing but polite but you have been peppering your answers with backhanded insults and no real suggestions.

Comment: there is no magic answer to your question.  this is not something that can easily be solves on a site like S.O